Aws Textract Async operations - from external document storage?
Friends,
I am creating a component that extracts documents for its content. Since there are multi page pdf documents, as per my understanding I need to use ‘ StartDocumentTextDetection’ async method. This method requires the document to be part of a S3 bucket in AWS? Right? All my documents are in an external , non-aws location. Can we pass byte array of an external document to the textract operations. Please let me know

https://repost.aws/questions/QUkpXpEmHBR6uci39_zdYqcA/aws-textract-not-accepting-remote-non-aws-document-url
AWS Textract operations wont support remote url! But I tried to use Azure Document Intelligence, that has an option to access remote documents!
